# Modify a button when the app is loaded (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, single-page-application

I've created, in Xcode, a single view application with a button containing the text "bad text".

I would like that the text of this button becomes "good text" when the app is loaded.

For this purpose :

- I've created an outlet from this button to my controller
- I've added a "load" method to my controller, which calls setTitle of the button
- I've called "load" of the controller in `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

When I launch the app, `load` is called, but the text of the button doesn't change. If I change the text of the button latter, for example when the user click on the button, it works.

My hypothesis is that when `load`is called, the outlet is not already created. Is it true ? How can I resolve this please ?

[edit] Here is the code in the AppDelegate :

```
FreqViewController* mainController = (FreqViewController*) self.window.rootViewController;
[mainController load];
return YES;
```

I didn't know that we shouldn't put code in the AppDelegate. So how can I do something when the controller is loaded ?

Comment: Where are you calling `load` from? Actually... WAT? You're trying to change a button title from the app delegate? You shouldn't be touching anything like this from the app delegate. If you want to change a button title use the View Controller to do it.

Comment: It depends what order your code is in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, show that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your viewController add beg'n method

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [yourButton setTitle:@"new title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

when the application appear your title will change.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know this method. I can accept your answer in 6 minutes.